Generic types in abstract classes
I am looking for a C# solution that allows me to create a base class (AParam) whose inherited classes (Param) can be generic in order to implement different, type-dependent versions of a function (Serialize()). Ultimately, I want to be able to do something like in the code block below. I know that C# does not support template specialization. Is there a good workaround?
void Start()
{
       List<AParam> tList = new List<AParam>();

       tList.Add(new Param<int>());
       tList.Add(new Param<bool>());

       tList[0].Serialize();
}

In accordance with the specialization of Param, the respective implementation should be called directly on APram without manually executing type checks internally.
I have tried various interface and class combinations, but cannot get a working result.

Can you not have a non-generic ParamBase class that the generic Param<T> derives from?

When you say it should be type specific, how do you mean that?
Do you mean that Serialize for Param should be fully different from Param?

Why do you want to write a type dependent custom serialization function in the first place? In most cases it seem much more appropriate to use something like json or protobuf for serialization.

Yes exactly, the Param is supposed to have ab different implementation for Serialize than e.g. Param.
We need a to convert the Param into a specific binary format.

In that case generics is the wrong tool. Because it's not generic.

public class AParam
{
    public virtual void Serialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Param<T> : AParam
{
    public T Val { get; set; }

    public override void Serialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Param");
    }
}

Were you thinking of something like this?
Now if you want something where Param<int> Serialize is different from Param<bool>, then im afraid generics wont get you far. The best you can try to do is:
public class ParamTester
{
    public static void TryItOut()
    {
        List<AParam> tList = new List<AParam>();

        tList.Add(new ParamInt());
        tList.Add(new ParamBool());

        tList[0].Serialize();
        tList[1].Serialize();
    }
}

public class AParam
{
    public virtual void Serialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Param<T> : AParam
{
    public T Val { get; set; }
}

public class ParamInt : Param<int>
{
    public override void Serialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Integer");
    }
}

public class ParamBool: Param<bool>
{
    public override void Serialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Boolean");
    }
}


"I'm afraid generics wont get you far." It depends on how "generic" Serialize is. Certainly if you have type-specific serialization logic then generics would be messy (using run-time type checks)

Exactly, the Serialize implementation is a different one for every type.

@SMSTJ Your answer contains text Now if you want something where Param<int> Serialize is different from Param<bool>,  but the <int> etc have been interpreted as HTML tags and have been lost in this view. I recommend surrounding with backticks or escaping the symbols to &lt etc
